# Google translation API not working

Tags: codeigniter, google-translate, google-translation-api

In my codeigniter application, I want to translate user input from english to urdu. I have been using below posted code for that but it is not working, i.i. it does not translates the text. I am not getting any error on browser's console.

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Google AJAX Search API Sample</title>
        <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=<KEY>" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("language", "1");            
            function initialize() {
                var text = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
                google.language.translate(text, 'en', 'ur', function(result) {
                    var translated = document.getElementById("translation");
                    if (result.translation) {
                        translated.innerHTML = result.translation;
                    }
                });
            }
            google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);  
        </script>            
    </head>
    <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
        <div id="text">This example text.</div>
        <div id="translation">Loading...</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just edited the question to remove the API key you exposed on the code. Please proceed to rotate your key.

Comment: To detect if it's a coding/library issue or not, could you please try running the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-nodejs)?